# Print status code from the post in a json-rpc call

Tags: python, json, request, http-status-codes, json-rpc

I have a working script that does the job just fine but I can't seem to figure out how to print the status code after the script runs. 
Can someone please review and provide some guidance and help?

```
import requests
import json


url = 'http://10.3.198.100/ins'
switchuser = 'user'
switchpassword = 'password'

myheaders = {'content-type' : 'application/json-rpc'}
payload = [
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "cli",
    "params": {
    "cmd": "vrf context management",
    "version": 1
    },
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "cli",
    "params": {
    "cmd": "ip route 192.168.255.0/24 10.3.198.130",
    "version": 1
  },
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "cli",
    "params": {
    "cmd": "copy run start",
    "version": 1
    },
    "id": 3
  }
 ]
 response = requests.post(url, data = json.dumps(payload), headers = myheaders, auth = (switchuser, switchpassword)).json()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are immediately calling `.json()` after your `.post()` returns. This means that you are throwing away the rest of the info from the response.

Try this instead:

```
response = requests.post(
    url,data=json.dumps(payload),
    headers=myheaders,
    auth=(switchuser,switchpassword))
json_response = response.json()
print(response.status_code)
```

Reference: http://docs.python-requests.org/

Comment: Bingo! That did it. Thank you very much! Do you have a link that you can share so I can read more about this and understand the structure? I was looking out on the web for an example but I couldn't find any.

Comment: I added a link to `requests`. If you go through its [quickstart](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/), I'm sure you'll understand how to use it.